# reusing configs across containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, config

What's the industry practice to have config passed and re-used for docker containers, some configs are common while some have custom values. for instance.

Notice product container has a custom config param. `My_CUSTOM_CONFIG`

```
customer:
  image: node
  build:
    context: ./Customer
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  environment:
    DATABASE_HOST: database
    DATABASE_NAME: MyDB
    DATABASE_USER: myusername
    DATABASE_PASSWORD: mypassword
    SERVICE_PORT: 80
  depends_on:
    - database

product:
  image: node
  container_name: product
  restart: on-failure
  build:
    context: ./Product
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  environment:
    DATABASE_HOST: database
    DATABASE_NAME: MyDB
    DATABASE_USER: myusername
    DATABASE_PASSWORD: mypassword
    SERVICE_PORT: 80
    My_CUSTOM_CONFIG: secret
  depends_on:
    - consul
    - database
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`env_file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file):

> Add environment variables from a file. Can be a single value or a list.

Put this in, say, `.env`:

```
DATABASE_HOST=database
DATABASE_NAME=MyDB
DATABASE_USER=myusername
DATABASE_PASSWORD=mypassword
SERVICE_PORT=80
```

And then use it in `docker-compose.yml`

```
customer:
  image: node
  build:
    context: ./Customer
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  env_file: .env
  depends_on:
    - database

product:
  image: node
  container_name: product
  restart: on-failure
  build:
    context: ./Product
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  env_file: .env
  environment:
    My_CUSTOM_CONFIG: secret
  depends_on:
    - consul
    - database
```

Comment: Documentation says to use `VAR=VAL` and not `VAR: VAL`